# Unity GUI elements - how do I chose whos on top?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

im making an inventory system in Unity, where I use GUI elements - GUIBox, and GUI images, which are my Item Icons... I also have a stacking system in the GUIBox, where I use the text field and padding to show the amount of items in that inventory... the problem is, the text showing the size of the stack, is hidden partially by the item icon... how do I make sure the text is on top of the item Icon?

Thanks ahead,
Oran :)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question truly, you want your specific UI game object always be in top and nothing overlaps on it.
so i guess you need to set the sibling of that UI element to be on top.

see this official documentation about sibling:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsFirstSibling.html

try both of these options and see which one can does your work. (sometimes you also need UI game objects go under other UI game objects, so these two are useful for both).

these two methods replace the position of game object two first or last child of the parent in hierarchy.